# Customizing a ecommerce shopping cart like magento for price comparison website

Tags: magento, e-commerce, vs-web-site-project

I am developing a price comparison website using web scraping. For frontend I am thinking of using ready to use ecommerce shopping cart like magento or similar. I went through the demo pages of such ecommerce sites and found that there are many modules that I dont require eg. order, shipping, payments, discounts etc. Also The database also needs some design changes. Is it possible to do these changes in them? Which ecommerce site will best serve my purpose? Or is there any other ready to use site that I can customize?

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid this question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow, which expects questions to be  about specific technical issues.

Answer (score 1):

### First

This is not the place for this type of answers. Try different fourms

### Second

Never tweak / redesign a software to do the work of another software. I am not able to remember the quote of goat in lion's fur one.